# Price to convert one line of Cobol code to a modern language?

Tags: cobol, code-conversion

I would like to know any prices you have heard of for one-to-one conversion projects from Cobol code to a modern language. We are talking about programs with several hundred thousand lines of code.

Comment: most likely there's not a one-to-one ratio between cobol and a modern language.

Comment: This question is too open-ended. I doubt if you will ever get a
satisfactory (meaningful) answer. That said, have a look at the [NACA Project](http://media-tech.blogspot.com/2009/01/project-naca-migration-from-ibm.html)
I don't know if the costs were outlined in any of their papers, but you should get some idea of how large/complex this sort of
project is.

Comment: If you could get a good work estimate based on one sentence (which is highly unlikely) then coming up with a price will still have a lot of factors to consider. And even if you could come up with a valid price it really is only valid right now and wouldn't be valid for another time (e.g. next year) and place with different market factors.

Comment: How could the question become more specific? I could never start describing the processes of the company, the architecture, nor the interfaces of the system, without it filling several documents. The number of users and the age of the system is also a bad indicator of anything. I still believe the question is highly relevant for many companies.

Comment: To be more specific, you could specify the environment (z/OS? HP/UX?), the compiler type (Cobol-66? Cobol-74? Cobol-85) and vendor (IBM? Microfocus? Fujitsu? Also, what is the problem domain? Accounting? Web serving? Inventory control? And what is your new target platform and language?

Comment: The cost to convert a line of COBOL has to take into account all that stuff you don't want to describe, because they affect the result.

Comment: Regarding NACA, you should read my discussion of this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029974/experience-migrating-legacy-cobol-pl1-to-java/1061829#1061829   You should read the rest of that thread for other opinions than mine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about market prices, not programming.

Comment: I will happily do it for $85/hour as long as it is from my house and I can wear my bunny slippers and have my own coffee machine to fuel me...

Answer (score 3):

I imagine it would be very difficult to accurately cost a conversion of this nature. Apart from the code, and understanding the business processes, you would also have to factor in changes for the new environment, running batch programs, print spooling, etc.

Instead of converting, have you checked out the possibility of changing the COBOL environment, i.e. running under .NET or JVM.

And COBOL is a modern language :-)

Comment: I know this is a very difficult question. But getting for example an interval (i.e. 10 cents to 1$ per line of code or maybe it should be 1000$ to 10000$ (I have no idea)) would be a lot better than not having an interval.